# How to use Javascript to check whether a value of a column in a Sharepoint list is either empty or null?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

So far I can retrieve the list based on a string I pass and even the column names but I can't figure out how to get the values of a specific column. Here is what I have so far.

```
function GetFieldList()
{
  var listname = document.getElementById("ListName").value;
  var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  this.web = ctx.get_web();
  ctx.load(this.web);
  this.list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listname);
  ctx.load(this.list);
  this.fields = this.list.get_fields();
  ctx.load(this.fields); 
  ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
```

Btw I'm using SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Did you check if `SP.ClientContext.get_current();` returns a Javascript Object?

Comment: I used the _typeof_ method to check what datatype ctx is and got _object_ as a result. Does that help?

Comment: @myEdu Are you trying to fetch data from particular field/column in sharepoint list ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is not full the client Context must run async method to load the values 
If you want correct way to get the values from SharePoint read the this documentation :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx
or you can use another library such as rest api or spservice .
Anyway the get_fields() return the fields list name not values.

Comment: agreed! there is no method to parse the results from the query

Comment: added method to parse the query.

Answer (score 0):

As you said `SP.ClientContext.get_current();` is an Javascript Object, so first of all you need to check if the property that you want to know if is null or empty, exists.

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
isPropertyEmptyOrNull = ctx.hasOwnProperty('myProperty') && (prop.myProperty === null or prop.myProperty === '' or prop.myProperty === undefined)
```

You found more details abour hasOwnProperty [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Answer (score 0):

Refer below code. This shows how to retrieve items from SharePoint list.

```
function GetItems() {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ListName');
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml("");
    collItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    context.load(collItems);
    context.executeQueryAsync(GetItemsSuccess, GetItemsFail);
}

function GetItemsSuccess() {

    var listItemEnumerator = collItems.getEnumerator();

    if (collItems.get_count() > 0) {

        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {

            var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

            /*
                retrieve specific fields (e.g. Title, FirstName...)
                Here 'Title' and 'FirstName' will be the internal name of the field you want to retrieve
            */
            var title = oListItem.get_item('Title');
            var firstName = oListItem.get_item('FirstName');

        }
    }
}

function GetItemsFail(sender, args) {
    // Error handler code 
}
```